# How we know the procedure is executed successfully (when there was a transaction)

Tags: mysql

When normally executed a sql query  we can gets returning integer value as positive to true and negative to false. But when we executed a procedure which has transaction or without any select query we can't have a return value with difference. How can we gets a result about if fired the procedure successfully.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713368/how-to-know-if-insert-query-succeeded-in-stored-proceedure. Check this here

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)